# What would be a literal translation of "Satan"?

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, ecclesiastical-latin, vulgata

In Ancient Greek, the Hebrew word *שָׂטָן* (*satan*, "adversary") is sometimes translated as *διάβολος* (*diábolos*, "betrayer") and sometimes adapted as *Σατανᾶς* (*Satanâs*).

In Latin, it seems like there would be three translation options: translate the word into Latin, transcribe the Greek, or transcribe the Hebrew. Jerome seems to have chosen the second and third exclusively, which is why we have Latin *diabolus* and *Satanas*.

But if he'd chosen the first, what would be an appropriate word? Something like *inimicus* "enemy" feels too tame for a fallen angel.

(This question arose while [answering another question about *Satanas*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/10598/406).)

---

P.S. Is the #english-to-latin tag appropriate when it's really more Hebrew-to-Latin and/or Greek-to-Latin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Adversarius" is in fact used at least once in the Vulgate to refer to the devil, so it presumably was felt to have a fitting meaning.

> Sobrii estote, et vigilate: quia **adversarius vester diabolus** tamquam leo rugiens circuit, quaerens quem devoret

(1 Petri 5:8)

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off, the Romans, themselves, referred to him as *Satana* in the Vulgate (cf: I Timothy 5:15 VULG). However, if you wanted to refer to him in the literal sense as the "enemy" or "adversary," you have several options:

> - *Advorsarius*
> - *Adversarius*
> - *Perduellis*

Seeing as *Perduellis* means "national enemy," I think that would be more appropriate here; however, since Satan is commonly referred to as "the Adversary," the other two would also be appropriate.